# Layout is being overlapped by buttons. How do I hide the buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been learning for a couple of weeks and have been struggling with layouts in this situation. It's just a small project intended for learning. Button upg calls the LinearLayout ShopL as a popup window but it overlaps.Basically i want the red buttons to be behind(hidden from) the blue Linearlayout (see picture).

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    tools:context="com.example.daniela.test003.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Total"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Total Geld"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/perClickShower"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="perClickShower"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/perSecondShower"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.262"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Total"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/perSecondShower"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="372dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="perSecondShower"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.262"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="btn1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="upg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/perSecondShower"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.892" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ShopL"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="81dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:baselineAligned="false"

            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this layout on multiple phones, you'll notice that the "bad" behavior (the buttons appearing even though they're "covered" by the linear layout) will only happen on phones with Android Lollipop or newer.

Lollipop introduced the concept of "elevation", and all buttons on Lollipop+ have elevation by default. Pressing on one of these buttons also *adds* elevation for the duration of the press (that's why the shadow the button casts on the background appears to grow).

Elevation works just like the real world; things with higher elevation appear above things with lower elevation. Your linear layout doesn't define an elevation value, and linear layouts don't have elevation by default, so its elevation is `0dp`. A button in the default resting state has an elevation of `2dp`. As long as the button's elevation is greater than the linear layout's, the button will appear "in front" of the linear layout.

An easy solution would be to add some large amount of elevation to your linear layout:

```
android:elevation="12dp"
```

This can have other side-effects, but it's possible it will just work for you.